# Why does my $watch only ever fire once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm factoring out some widget and the `$watch` expression works perfectly having all in one file but now I moved the relevant controller part into a new controller and the markup into a new html and the `$watch` fires exactly once after initialization but not when editing typing in the associated input.

JS:

```
app.controller('getRecipientWidgetController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log("controller initializing")
    var testReceivingAddress = function(input) {
        console.log("change detected")
    }
    $scope.$watch("addressInput", testReceivingAddress)
} ])
```

HTML of wrapper:

```
<ng-include
    src="'partials/getRecipientWidget.html'"
    ng-controller="getRecipientWidgetController"
    ng-init="recipient=cert"> <!-- ng-init doesn't influence the bug. -->
</ng-include>
```

HTML of `partials/getRecipientWidget.html`:

```
<md-text-float ng-model="addressInput"></md-text-float>
```

I suspect there is some scope voodoo going on? I left the `ng-init` in to make clear what I want to achieve: build an obviously more complex, reusable widget that in this instance would work on `$scope.cert` as its `recipient`.

Comment: Just for giggles, what happens when you inject the rootscope and call $watch on that?

Comment: @dustmouse no change. Exactly the same bug/behavior.

Comment: As said by floribon in his answer, learn about the so-called "dot rule".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is probably because `ng-include` will create a new inherited scope on the included HTML, hence `$scope.addressInput` in your controller is not the same reference as `$scope.addressInput` in `getRecipientWidget.html`

Well it's not easy to explain, but you should either put `ng-controller` within the HTML of `getRecipientWidget.html` (and not on the div above that includes it), OR you can use an object such as `something.addressInput` instead of the raw `addressInput` which avoids references issues on raw types (number/string).

Comment: Yeah! Thank you a ton! `something` started working here. :) Not sure which of your solutions to pick but having choice is a nicer problem to have than my bug :)

Comment: Pick the second one. Using the dot notation is seen as a best practive in AngularJS, and doing this consistently means you won't have this bug come back to bite you (or a colleague of yours that would change the HTML)

Comment: I just tested the first one and learned (you might elaborate/add that to your reply) that both controllers ended up operating on the same scope. Will go with `something` and the two scopes(?).

Comment: Using the dot is indeed safe, but I would recommend doing both: sounds like `getRecipientWidgetController` has to be the controller of `getRecipientWidget.html` so there is no reason to have it separated. In fact, the cleanest, 3rd solution would be to use a directive instead of ngInclude+controller, that is precisely what they do so might be a good time to learn them :)

Answer (score 3):

ng-include creates new scope.

Try this

```
<md-text-float ng-model="$parent.addressInput"></md-text-float>
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/jQ9zzSdx0Lit6W8ewsNR?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you but I guess floribon did a good job at explaining what's going on. Using `$parent` would be a third option probably.